# How to allow connections in zimbra/mail client?

Tags: permissions, bash, centos6, zimbra

I installed a Zimbra server into CentOS 6, enter the admin panel via web HTTPS over port 7071, the problem is I can not access the web mail client (port 445), I can only access via localhost. I reviewed this port from bash:

```
[root@host etc]# netstat -antp | grep 445
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:445 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 15751/java
[root@host etc]# cat /proc/15751/cmdline
/opt/zimbra/java/bin/java-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8-server-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2-Djava.awt.headless=true-Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=60-Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC-XX:PermSize=128m-XX:MaxPermSize=350m-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=1-verbose:gc-XX:+PrintGCDetails-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow-Xloggc:/opt/zimbra/log/gc.log-XX:-UseGCLogFileRotation-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=20-XX:GCLogFileSize=4096K-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true-Xss256k-Xms6410m-Xmx6410m-Xmn1602m-Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/zimbra/mailboxd/work-Djava.library.path=/opt/zimbra/lib-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/zimbra/mailboxd/common/endorsed-Dzimbra.config=/opt/zimbra/conf/localconfig.xml-Djetty.home=/opt/zimbra/mailboxd-DSTART=/opt/zimbra/mailboxd/etc/start.config-jar/opt/zimbra/mailboxd/start.jar--module=zimbra,server,servlet,servlets,jsp,jmx,resources,websocket,ext,plus,rewrite,monitor,continuation,webapp,setuidjetty.home=/opt/zimbra/mailboxd/opt/zimbra/mailboxd/etc/jetty.xml
```

From localhost I have no problems but from the outside can not, I tried to modify the jetty.xml found in zimbra settings and restart the mailbox but the service I zimbra this file overwrites the previous settings.

How I can set zimbra correctly so you can access the web mail client from any external ip?

Comment: As a side-note: block the admin port with the firewall. Check CVE 2019 9670.

Answer (score 0):

1) it should be 443 not 445, it's standard HTTPS
2) if not it's 8443 (or 443 via nginx proxy) pending your install
3) disable your firewall (temporarily)

Did you install it with their RPM? what package? 8.6.1GA?  re-run the installer you may have missed something and make sure all services are running

```
sudo su - zimbra
zmcontrol status
```

Comment: zmcontrol status all services are up, yes, i use rpm package, i use apache2 with 80 and 443 in use with website. Realy need use a reverse proxy?, cannot use firewall and have selinux in disabled mode. 80 and 443: webserver, 7071, 445 (ssl) and 446 (not ssl): zimbra.

Comment: Can you post the output of status

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=shW206jy can access via localhost but not via external ip

Comment: iptables -L also please

Comment: iptables are disabled. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=rpbR8kNt , I just checked that also works without SSL (446) does not work with ssl (445) even though the administration panel (7071) if it works with SSL. I want to work with SSL.

Comment: Works redefine ports with zmprov ms: zimbraMailPort, zimbraMailSSLPort and zimbraMailMode.